# How to show or hide button in a datagrid header?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, header, accordion, code-behind, show-hide

I am developing the silverlight application. I am new to the silverlight 4. I am using the following link for reference in my accordion control

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/166937/376318.aspx

In the above link with AccordionItem.Header I am able to show or hide the button control but I am not able to handle the click event on the button control in code behind. So I have used the AccordionItem.HeaderTemplate in my code. I have 4 buttons in my header control. I am able to show and hide the button by using the above link. With HeaderTemplate I am able to handle the click event on the button control in code behind.  With HeaderTemplate I am not able to access the button control placed inside HeaderTemplate in code behind. I am getting the NullReferenceException error "The Object reference not set to an instance of the object" How to resolve the above issue ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can access the control placed inside the HeaderTemplate in code behind ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Comment: Now I have enabled the button in the header by using the following answer. For this purpose I have written the code in code behind. Is it possible to do this task in xaml instead of writting the code in code behind ? Can you please provide me any link or solution through which I can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the button in the header of datagrid with the following statement in code behind

```
accordiocntl.SelectionMode = AccordionSelectionMode.ZeroOrOne;
```

You can refer the link https://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/134010/301229.aspx for more details